# What is the impact of windowing function on time series

Tags: time-series, spectral-analysis

Greeting

I would like to know what is the impact of windowing functions like Hanning,... on a time series.

Is it possible to finde anomalies using windowing functions?

**EDIT**

I have a time series, which contains integer values (470,471,472,472,473,471,...) I try to find anomalies in this vector of value. As I have understood, with Wavelet transform , FFT, and moving average .

As I know any discontinuity between the 1st and last time sample (i.e., a jump in the value ) will contribute to the frequency spectrum in FFT, but we should use windowing to detect these anomalies. It means, I should calculate FFT for my time series and then I should run a window function like hanning or etc. on the result to find anomalies, Is it right?

Comment: Please explain what you are trying to do. Do you mean using windowing with spectral estimation, or with kernel smoothing, or something else? And what sort of anomalies are you looking for? It is impossible to answer such a general question.

Comment: thnak you sir, I have edited my post